# Citations in VIM: the fzf-Bibtex PlugIn

Tags: plugin-fzf, fzf, plugin

I try to use the plugin [fzf-Bibtex](https://github.com/msprev/fzf-bibtex) to insert citations in a scientific paper.

I have installed all dependencies and plugins.

These have been added to my .vimrc:

```
Plug 'msprev/fzf-bibtex' 
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } } 
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
```

As mentioned in the documentation, I have used the VIM command line:

```
:bibtex-ls
```

But got the error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: bibtex-ls
```

- Has anyone tried to use this plugin?
- Is that the right command to use?
- If not, how did you manage to use citations with the PlugIn?

Comment: bibtex-ls is a command-line tool that makes it easy to integrate with fzf. From vim, you would need to use the fzf support to invoke bibtex-ls

Answer (score 1):

The command to type to test it is in your path is

```
:!bibtex-ls
```

You are executing an external programme, not a vim command.

However, if you want to actually use fzf-bibtex in Vim in a meaningful way, you need to integrate it into your vim-fzf setup [as described in the manual](https://github.com/msprev/fzf-bibtex#vim-.integration).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!